# Is there a way to restrict specific service principal in azure from creating resources unless it is tagged with specific tag?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a tf.json file which creates a service principal in Azure.

This service principal is assigned a custom role, also created by the Terraform, with specific permissions.

I need to find a way to enforce restrictions on this particular service principal, preventing it from creating resources within my Azure subscription unless those resources are tagged with a specific key-value pair.

For instance, I want to restrict the creation of resource groups made by this service principal so they can only be created within the specific subscription ID defined in the Terraform script, only if they have a specific tag, such as "bla":"bla."

tried the following

```
"azurerm_policy_definition": {
      "custom_policy": {
        "name": "deny-resource-group-creation",
        "display_name": "Deny resource group creation without the required tag",
        "policy_type": "Custom",
        "mode": "All",
        "policy_rule": "{ \"if\": {\n            \"allOf\": [\n                {\n                    \"field\": \"type\",\n                    \"equals\": \"Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups\"\n                },\n                {\n                    \"not\": {\n                        \"field\": \"tags['bla']\",\n                        \"equals\": \"bla\"\n                    }\n                }\n            ]\n        },\n        \"then\": {\n            \"effect\": \"deny\"\n        }}"
      }
    },
    "azurerm_resource_policy_assignment" : {
      "resource_group_creation_policy_assignment": {
        "name":  "resource-group-creation-policy-assignment",
        "resource_id": "${azuread_service_principal.cloud_sp.id}",
        "policy_definition_id" :"${azurerm_policy_definition.custom_policy.id}"
      }
    }
```

I was expecting to be able to assign the policy to the service principal, but I
wasn't able to do so

Comment: I suspect you can craft a policy that will do what you want, and assign it to the management group, subscription or resource group.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to restrict specific service principal in azure from creating resources unless it is tagged with specific tag?

I agree with @*Narthring* regarding azure policy assignment.

`Azure Policy` applies only to `management groups`, `subscriptions` and `resource groups`. It is not possible to assign `Azure Policy` to a `service principal`. you can follow the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/scope#definition-location) for more information about `Azure Policy` assignment.

```
 provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "custom_policy" {
  name         = "deny-resource-group-creation"
  display_name = "Deny resource group creation without the required tag"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  mode         = "All"

  policy_rule = <<POLICY_RULE
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
            "field": "type",
             "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "field": "tags['bla']",
          "equals": "bla"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
POLICY_RULE
}

resource "azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment" "example" {
  name                 = "deny-resource-group-creation"
  policy_definition_id = azurerm_policy_definition.custom_policy.id
  subscription_id      = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
}
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

After assigning the policy to the specified scope, it denies the creation of **Resource Group** without `bla:bla` tag,  as shown below.

[image]

Reference: [Understand scope in Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/scope)

Comment: This basically prevents all the users from creating resource groups unless it is tagged by the specific tag, which is not the behavior I'm looking for, 
I want to restrict only some specific service principal/user from doing that,
not for all the subscription,
is it possible to do it? maybe by other ways than policies

Comment: Yes. Do you want to prevent any user?

Comment: No, I want to just prevent the service principal created by the terraform.
I also have azuread_application created by the terraform, which includes the service principal if it helps to get the required behavior

Comment: Basically, Azure policy assignment is assigned to Management group, Subscription and Resource Group, so it's not possible to restrict specific user or Service Principal.

Comment: is there a way other than policy to get similar behavior?

Comment: You can achieve it using RBAC, but it's not possible to restrict it with tags

Comment: Let me know if you have any queries?

Comment: Can you please give me examples of how to achieve it using RBAC via terraform, 
and also maybe examples of conditions that may help in my case,? maybe name convention of resources?

Comment: Do you want to use Terraform to restrict the creation of resource groups by specific service principals with RBAC?

Comment: Yes if it is possible, but not to restrict him from creation,I mean I still want him to have the permission that allows him to create the resource group, but maybe under some conditions, maybe name conventions, or if there is any other way

Comment: Using RBAC, it is not possible to impose naming conditions when creating resources.

Comment: Create a Service Principal and assign the same SP to a subscription. Only this SP will be able to create a resource group.

Comment: Here is the code to assign RBAC role to SP in Terraform:
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.object_id
} , Follow this [TF doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/service_principal#example-usage) to create SP using terraform

Comment: As I see in azure documentation "Currently, conditions can be added to built-in or custom role assignments that have blob storage or queue storage data actions"
Which is not my case 
So in my case I this it is only about assigning the permissions without the conditions, which I already have in my terraform
I do assign actions using azurerm_role_assignment, the ideas is to restrict the service principal for some actions, such as creating and deleting based on conditions, like tags, names etc.. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Hi @AmalKhalaily, as of now it's not possible to achieve your scenario.